# TF map_fn too slow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a custom layer in tensorflow which should a apply a function `f` to the incoming tensor. So, if the batch consists of the tensors `T = [T1, T2, ..., Tn]` it should return the tensor `[f(T1), f(T2), ..., f(Tn)]`.

The intended way to do this seems to be to use the `tf.map_fn` function. However, I notices that this functions is awfully slow. Below is a MWE which, on my laptop, yields the following perfomance:

- ~61us/step without identity layer
- ~62us/step with    identity layer `output=inputs`
- ~120us/step with identity layer `output=tf.map_fn(...)`

Is there any way to speed up iterating over the batch size?

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

class Identity(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Identity, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, inputs)
#        output = inputs
        return output  

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        Identity(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=100)
```

Comment: No, not like that, `tf.map_fn` is slow, as you can see in your absolutely minimal example, and `tf.while_loop` is even slower. You can change the `parallel_iterations` parameter, but it still has to operate each element individually. You have to do things vectorized style whenever possible, use TensorFlow operations that act over the whole array.

Comment: (to be fair, 120us is actually really fast, I mean `tf.map_fn` is slow compared to the vectorized alternative, whenever this is one exists)

Comment: What is the shape of the input in your case?

Comment: @MikhailBerlinkov I am working on a modification of the standard dropout layer. The input shape is whatever comes out for the previous layer.

Comment: Well, I think the only ways to speed up computation is either through vectorisation (and using existing efficient operations) or implementing your own lower-level parallelizable code.